# Symfony parent ACL (objects acces rights inheritance)

Tags: symfony, acl

i just installed the Symfony ACL. I want to ask you how the `parent_object_identity_id` field from the `acl_object_identities` table can be automatically completed, also all data in the `acl_object_identity_ancestors` table.

I have for example Category & Product entities, I would like to use products as children of categories and use ACL rights in cascade: if you have access to the category ID 7, you should have also access to all products from that category.

I was thinking sonata:admin:generate-object-acl can set all this data, it put instead empty values for `parent_object_identity_id` field.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome! Usually we try to avoid thank taglines in the questions to keep them tidier, you can read why in here: "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)".

Answer (score 2):

Its a little bit late-response.. but I faced the same problem a few month ago..

I just published the **[AclTree Bundle](https://github.com/GoDisco/AclTreeBundle)**, which is a bundle that solving the exact problem you faced.

https://github.com/GoDisco/AclTreeBundle

I hope it may helps you :)